# Laravel: Not able to access belongsToMany relation in nested whereHas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using whereHas in nested where clause but i am not able to do so. Following is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function scopePickedUser($query, $pickedTypeID)
    {
        return $query->where(function($query) use ($pickedTypeID)
        {
            $query->whereHas('photos', function($query) use ($pickedTypeID)
            {
                 $query->whereTypeId($pickedTypeID);
            });


            if($condition){
                $query->orWhere('another_column_id',$var);
            }
        });
    }

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Photo::class);
    }
}
```

If i call, `App\Models\User::pickedUser(4)->get()` i am getting error `BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::photos()'`. Why is that? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try this once App\Models\User::with('photos')->pickedUser(4)->get()

Answer (score 0):

Just refer laravel [with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for Eager Loading and Lazy Eager Loading . I guess you can try these two types

```
App\Models\User::with('photos')->pickedUser(4)->get()
```

Or

```
public function scopePickedUser($query, $pickedTypeID)
    {
        $query->load('photos');
        return $query->where(function($query) use ($pickedTypeID)
        {
            $query->whereHas('photos', function($query) use ($pickedTypeID)
            {
                 $query->whereTypeId($pickedTypeID);
            });


            if($condition){
                $query->orWhere('another_column_id',$var);
            }
        });
    }
```